# How to handle errors with std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling, dynamic-memory-allocation

`std::vector` allocates memory which can fail, but the constructor can't return anything, should we use `try` and `catch` every time we declare an `std::vector` ?

I know this question might have already been answered but I didn't find anything, please comment links.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to do anything meaningful if `std::vector` threw an exception like that?

Comment: To end the program because we can't use a vector that has no memory.

Comment: If the best course of action is just to terminate the program, then make the constructor `noexcept`. Then an exception will crash the program. Considering what "out of memory" means, that probably is for the best.

Comment: I mean to do something to tell the user that threre is a problem.

Comment: The thing about exceptions is that if you don't catch them anywhere, they eventually terminate your program. So littering a code base with exception handlers that do noting but aborting the problem is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I could imagine a situation where an operation requires making a vector of DWORDs representing the pixels in a **big** bitmap. If construction fails due to BAD_ALLOC, then I *could* suggest that the user reduces the size of the bitmap.

Comment: but using exceptions handlers every time we create or push back to a vector is a lot of works, it is maybe even simpler in C.

Comment: You may be able handle the problem in an outer scope depending on the design of your application.

Comment: @rsjaffe — marking a function that can throw exceptions `noexcept` is generally a bad idea. Functions higher up in the call chain may need to do cleanup, and short-circuiting the normal stack unwinding prevents that. The decision to abort an application is a matter of application design, not local coding.

Comment: I did some tests and if I throw, the destructors of the objects in the scope get called. Thanks @drescherjm, this seems to be a nice solution.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can also imagine scenarios where you can handle exceptions. But the question was whether OP's situation is one such scenario.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK - no problem. I wasn't sure if your original question was rhetorical or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the default allocator used in `std::vector` can throw in *critical* conditions like "out-of-memory". Unhandled exceptions automatically call `std::terminate()`, which by itself is a good enough handler for these situations, since they should normally never occur (on modern systems with virtual memory, `std::bad_alloc` is rarely a sign of insufficient memory, and instead a sign of an error in the program, like trying to allocate a negative amount).

So "do nothing" is a good enough way to handle a potentially throwing `std::vector`.

On Linux you'd get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc', what():  std::bad_alloc, Aborted (core dumped)`.

Unfortunately there are platforms (e.g. Windows) where `std::terminate()` prints nothing.

For best portability you can thus `catch` all `std` exceptions globally to print some meaningful error message just before exiting. For example:

```
int main() {
    try {

        // program code ...

    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to treat any additional threads, if any, in a similar way.

In any case, an individual `try`-`catch` per `std::vector` instance would be overkill.